# Добавление нового языка на сайт с сохранением функционала на Laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

уважаемые гуру веба.
Я - начинающий разработчик практически без опыта и так сложилось, что ко мне попал  один из проектов нашей компании, куда нужно добавить новые инструменты и функционал. Написан он на Laravel, с которым я раньше практически не сталкивался.
Суть:
Сейчас приложение предоставляет возможность работать с информацией о клиентах и о их сайтах. Добавляются новые записи, меняются статусы, генерируется и выводится статистика. 
Моя задача в том, чтобы в рамках этого же приложения разделить всех пользователей на две языковых группы, которые между собой никак не пересекаются. То есть, все записи, стастистика и пользователи этих двух групп существуют отдельно друг от друга с отдельными базами данных. Переключаться между этими группами могут только пользователи со статусом "админ".
Объясните на пальцах (чем подробнее, тем лучше), каким образом лучше реализовать это дело.
Спасибо!

Comment: По вопросу не понятно, есть уже языковое разделение? есть ли вообще мультиязычность?

Comment: Языкового разделения нету. Вообще, мультиязычность - второстепенное дело. Главная цель - разбить всех пользователей на две группы с отдельными базами и чтоб они не пересекались. Если это удасться реализовать, то написать новый словарь для новой локали уже труда не составит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уже есть отделенные базы, то:

1) В конфиге с настройками базы, обычно config/database.php, создай новые подключения к примеру **mysql_other_user**, пропиши все данные.

2) В контроллере определяй группу

```
$user = \Auth::user();
    if($user->group === 'guest'){
    $db_connection = 'mysql_other_user';
}
```

А дальше уже как сам хочешь работай с базой

```
DB::connection($db_connection)->table('table')->get()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Направило на путь